# не работает условие if ……

Tags: python-3.x

Не работает код начал практиковаться в питоне и че то по моей логике не работает заранее спасибо

```
a = int(input("how old are you"))
for i in range(0, 51):
    if a == i:
        print("молодой")
    else:
        print("1")
```

что не писал ответ выводиться много 1

Comment: Попробуйте добавить в вопрос словами ожидаемый алгоритм работы программы. Может поможет и самому прийти к ответу.

Comment: Данный код как раз очень наглядно показывает, что условие If прекрасно работает

Answer (score 1):

В вашем цикле на каждом шаге при i от 0 до 51 будет выводиться '1'; если выполнится условие a == i (a совпадет с i), то вывод одной из строк будет "молодой". В данном примере условие if работает вполне корректно

Пример выполнения программы при вводе значения '5':

```
how old are you5
1
1
1
1
1
молодой
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
```

Comment: [Почему не следует выкладывать код/данные/ошибки в виде скриншотов?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/12120/385375)

Answer (score 1):

Если подразумевается, что программа должна проверять ввод на попадание в интервал [0:51) и если условие удовлетворяется выводить 'молодой' или '1' в противном случае, то цикл не нужен:

```
a = int(input("how old are you"))
if 0 <= a <= 50:
    print("молодой")
else:
    print("1")
```

Но если непременно хочется цикл, то он должен выглядеть как-то так:

```
a = int(input("how old are you"))
for i in range(0, 51):
    if a == i:
        print("молодой")
        break
    else:
        continue
else:
    print('1')
```

Но так делать не надо никогда.